# Segue specific value in prepare for segue

Tags: ios, swift, tags, segue, viewcontroller

Right now I have 2 buttons that segue the textfield data from vc1 to vc2. I would like to have the top button segue whatever is in the textfield to vc2. I would like the bottom button to just segue to the next vc. Right now both buttons segue the data from the textfield to the next vc.

[image]

```
    import UIKit
class ViewController: UIViewController {
@IBOutlet var textfield: UITextField!
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    guard let c2 = segue.destination as? twoViewController else {return}
    c2.ss = textfield.text
}}

class twoViewController: UIViewController {
var ss: String!
@IBOutlet var datalbl: UILabel!
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    datalbl.text = ss
}}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Passing Data between View Controllers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5210535/passing-data-between-view-controllers)

Comment: BTW, `class` names should start with a capital letter by convention in Swift: `TwoViewController`.  Notice the syntax highlighting above didn't make your class name blue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two ways you could handle this:

**Use the sender and set the button's tag value**

The `sender` in `prepare(for:sender:)` is the button that was pressed, so you can set unique tag values for your 2 buttons and then check that:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    guard let c2 = segue.destination as? twoViewController else {return}
    if (sender as? UIButton)?.tag == 1 {
        c2.ss = textfield.text
    }
}
```

**Set identifiers for the segues and check them in `prepare(for:sender:)`**

Since you have two segues, click on the segue arrows in the Storyboard and set their identifiers in the *Attributes Inspector*.  You could set the segue identifier for the top button to `"sendTextField"` and then check for that in `prepare(for:sender:)`:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    guard let c2 = segue.destination as? twoViewController else {return}
    if segue.identifier == "sendTextfield" {
        c2.ss = textfield.text
    }
}
```